# Embed camera in app

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to create a QR scanner application. The QR scanning part is working but the scan process in connected with button. I want to change the logic so the camera will be already opened when the user opens the application and only after that click the button to scan. Anyone had that experience with nativescript angular? i've installed the plugins for barcodescanner and camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Anna, I believe you can use the barcode scanning from the firebase sdks now for what you're trying to achieve. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md#barcode-scanning

The actual `camera` plugin for NS uses the camera on the device so it launches the camera application and is not embeddable within your own application. There are ways to embed a camera into your own app layouts, I helped write this plugin which achieves that (https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) but it does not have barcode scanning.